# Problem with my sound devices

Tags: recording, pro-tools, audio-interfaces, troubleshooting

So I just hooked up a Tascam US 1800. Installation went fine and my computer recognizes it as my default sound device. However, for some reason, whenever I use Pro-Tools, it only sends the Pro Tools audio to the interface. Literally EVERYTHING else audio related is sent to other sound devices. I believe it is being caused by ASIO4ALL, which automatically boots every time I run Pro Tools. When Pro Tools/ASIO is off, everything is sent to the Tascam just fine. It's only when I run Pro Tools/ASIO4ALL do I start to get problems. I have tried disabling all other sound devices with no luck. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If ever you post technical problems to a forum always include software version, system spec, OS, driver versions at the least.

I'll presume you're running Windows. When a program uses an Asio driver it connects directly to the audio interface, bypassing Windows. So Asio can only be used by one piece of software - It's either Pro Tools or Windows not both of them together.

I'd also use the Tascam Asio drivers as they're purpose designed for your system.

Comment: Yes, likely related to multiple audio device drivers overlapping or just using incompatible driver to a wrong device. One should always use vendor-supplied drivers, if such exist. 

Comment: the asio thing.. it depends on the drivers. maybe it's true with asio4all, but i've used a perfectly fine native multiclient driver (manufacturer is less relevant), that routed everything through the same interface without conflicts, questions, or need for settings, daw or not..


Comment: @georgi.m That's news to me. Which one do you use? And do you get the same level of performance (latency etc) out of it?